# Unable to render functional component with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react hooks. I'm trying to use the following component as the filter input element for one of the columns in a ReactTable component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker/DatePickerDialog'

import '../styles/style.less'

export default function DateRange({ startLabel = 'From', endLabel = 'To' } = {}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="date-range">
      <input type="text" placeholder={startLabel} onClick={() => setOpen(true)} />
      <input type="text" placeholder={endLabel} />
      <DatePicker open={open} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

but the render fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: This looks okay. There must be something else going on in your code that you're not showing.

Comment: How are you calling `DateRange`?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for pointing it out. I was calling `DateRange()` and it worked after I changed it to `<DateRange />`